# How to make pulseaudio use a surround profile?

Tags: pulseaudio

I recently upgraded my Pi 400 to the latest Os version that now uses Pulseaudio by default. I have my Pi connected to an AVR (Harman Kardon 151S) that is connected to a 5.1 setup of loudspeakers.

`speaker-test -c6 -D hw:0` correctly plays sound from each loudspeaker including the subwoofer.

However, when I try to play a [test file](https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/multichannel.html) in Kodi, MPV or VLC, the surround channels are played trough the front loudspeakers and the subwoofer is silent.

I suspect this is because pulseaudio wrongly offers just a Digital Stereo output (a portion of `pacmd list-cards`):

```
 profiles:
            output:digital-stereo: Digital Stereo Output (priority 5100, available: unknown)
            off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
```

How can I make it use a 5.1 profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, enable the correct number of speakers in `daemon.conf` (it's eiter in `/etc/pulse/` or in `~/.config/pulse/`). For 5.1 setup that would be:

```
default-sample-channels=6
```

Then load the channel mapper module from `default.pa` (again, it's eiter in `/etc/pulse/` or in `~/.config/pulse/`). For 5.1 setup that would be:

```
load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Comment: Hm, I just installed the latest release from January 28 2022 and I do get surround sound by default, just the mapping of the speakers is completely off! Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Actually, that one is fixed by setting  [Mapping hdmi-surround]  in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf` to `channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,front-center,rear-left,rear-right` as per https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1959978&hilit=hdmi+surround+alsa#p1959978

In current release, surround works out of the box and the stops above are not needed. But I guess given how the original question is structured, this is the way to go, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue but got a little progress:
with

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink name=HDMI device=hw:0,0 channels=6 tsched=0
```

there was coming sound from the right surround speaker instead of the front left ([here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=207610) is the reference). So now only the new module needs to be adjusted to play the correct channels.
Thats's only a direction, when I find more about it I will share it.

Comment: That would be great! I am waiting for the new OS release for my next try!

Comment: Have you ever found more?

Comment: See my comment below to Dmitry Grigoryev answer - that shows how to fix the wrong placement of speakers.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the fix which allows you to even switch between Stereo and 5.1 at runtime, without touching the pulseaudio CLI.

Pulseaudio manages the input/output configuration through so-called profile set configuration files. More [information on this is available upstream](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Backends/ALSA/Profiles/).

The thing is, the profile shipped with pulseaudio for the raspberry Pi HDMI output ... only contains stereo (as of bullseye).

```
[General]
auto-profiles = yes

[Mapping digital-stereo]
description = Digital Stereo
device-strings = hw:%f
fallback = yes
priority = 1
direction = output
channel-map = left,right
paths-output = hdmi-output-0
```

In order to be able to switch between stereo and 5.1, you can do the following:

1. Place the following in a convenient location, I chose `/etc/pulse/profile-sets/rpi-hdmi.conf` (creating the directories):

   ```
   [General]
   auto-profiles = yes

   [Mapping digital-stereo]
   description = Digital Stereo
   device-strings = hw:%f
   priority = 1
   direction = output
   channel-map = left,right
   paths-output = hdmi-output-0

   [Mapping hdmi-surround]
   description = Digital Surround 5.1
   device-strings = hw:%f
   paths-output = hdmi-output-0
   channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,center,rear-left,rear-right
   priority = 3
   direction = output
   ```
2. Disable udev in your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` by adding a `#` in front of the line `load-module module-udev-detect`.
3. Load the sink manually by adding, to the bottom of the `default.pa`, the following:

   ```
   load-module module-alsa-card card_name=hdmi sink_name=alsa_output.hw_0_0 device_id=b1 tsched=false profile_set=/etc/pulse/profile-sets/rpi-hdmi.conf
   ```
4. Restart pulseaudio or the entire Raspberry Pi

You should now be able to switch between modes in the configuration tab of the `pavucontrol` utility. If your Pi is running headless (without any screen), you can access the pulse server remotely using `PULSE_SERVER=1.2.3.4 pavucontrol`, where you need to substitute `1.2.3.4` with the IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Make sure to adapt the path to your modified `rpi-hdmi.conf` if you put it in a different location.

This is tested to work on a Raspberry Pi 2B running latest Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye, connected to a Denon AVR-1910. I use a custom boot config because I have no TV attached and I also don't have the Denon online all the time, so the Pi may not detect it properly as HDMI sink:

```
dtparam=audio=on

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_edid_file=1
hdmi_force_edid_audio=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=5
hdmi_pixel_encoding=1
```